# Fill input field with GET value

Tags: php, html, get

This is my Code.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   Passwort ändern
   <form name="test" method="POST" action="ausgabe.php">
       <br>
       Email: <input name="pwchg_email_eingabe" type="var" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($_GET['email']); ?>" >
       <br><br>
       Altes Passwort: <input name="pwchg_altes_pw_eingabe" type="password">
       <br><br>
       Passwort: <input name="pwchg_pw_eingabe" type="password">
       <br><br>
       erneut Passwort: <input name="pwchg_verify_pw_eingabe" type="password">
       <input type="submit" value="Abschicken">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This...

```
Email: <input name="pwchg_email_eingabe" type="var" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($_GET['email']); ?>" >
```

is not working... Can you help me?

I want to get my `$_GET` into the input field.

EDIT: I'm calling it with: `accdelete.php?email='A@A.DE'`

Comment: _is not working_... Eh? `type=var` is a new input type?

Comment: I don't see a `type` of `var` in [**Form <input> types**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Form_<input>_types).

Comment: How are you calling this page ? Is it something like `page.php?email=info@mail.me` ?

Comment: I'm calling the website with `accdelete.php?email='A@A.DE'`

Comment: type="email" I think u have to use this input type and it is automatically validated when submitted

Comment: BTW, if you are below PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` is **not** enabled by default. See [short_open_tag](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

Comment: How is it correct? I changed `var` to `email` and to `text`, it isn't working.

Comment: I just created a page with that code and accessed `foo.php?email='A@A.DE'` and I see a field filled with `'A@A.DE'`. This problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot that. Everything works, except that the field is always empty.

Comment: @FirstOne What did you use as value?

Comment: @Lukas I copy-pasted your code. So, exactly what you have in your question is what I used xD

Comment: Add a print.  htmlspecialchars returns a string, it does not print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's been dealt with. I took another browser. Now it works.**

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.

best regards,

*Lukas*

Edit: I changed the Browser to *Firefox*

Comment: plz explain your solution so that someone else would get help